# Why is apple taking a 46% cut instead of 30%?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I just looked at adding some in app purchases, and when I look at the difference between 'price' and 'proceeds' the apple cut is 46%. Anyone able to explain this, and is there a fix?

I'm Swedish, if relevant.

Comment: Hey it is because of some countries has their own Tax on top of apple in-app purchase. So if a user is purchasing for example from Japan, then Japan government apply some tax. so you total revenue goes down for those countries. Also there is provision to file a declaration form that you doesn't belong to the buyer country and you can get the exemption from the taxes. I will send you the link for related Apple document.

Comment: Thanks for actually getting an answer instead of more downvotes :> This isn't all that obvious for a new developer. I was worried it was because I'm based in Sweden.

Comment: @Cesar : I think you will not be downvoted if you posted this question on apple stack exchange - http://apple.stackexchange.com/  or in Quora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out it's the countries tax policies that can highly change the percentage you get. You can download a CSV file with all proceeds and calculate the actual percentages. General rule of thumb is 30% + VAT

I downloaded the file for your: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14159989/pricing_matrix.csv